# "Crossover" SQL Server 2012 cluster? How to implement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008, database-administration, server-administration

Is it possible to create a "crossover" cluster, idea is to use first Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on one physical machine and database on him as primary (and just 4 insert, update and delete), on the other hand, second Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on other physical machine to be used for reports (just to read data)... And if one of them stop other one is going to be used as primary and for reports.

Comment: Not sure you can do that.  I'd look into replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in SQL Server 2012! You can read more about SQL 2012 AlwaysOn functionality using the link below:

[Active Secondaries: Readable Secondary Replicas (AlwaysOn Availability Groups)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878253%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)